# namespace question in c++ how to use "using namespace"

Tags: c++

I have a very basic question about namespace

when should I use "`using namespace A::B`"?

I know I shouldn't use it in header files, how about .cpp file? In my `test.cpp`:

```
namespace A{
namespace B{
namespace C{
      A::B::Object obj = ....
}
}
}
```

the full namespace is `A::B::Object` as I have right now, Do I actually need `A::B`? Can I just have `Object obj = ....`? Should I use `using namespace A::B` and then have `Object obj = ....`?  I am not sure what this actually means:

```
    namespace A{
    namespace B{
    namespace C{
          .....
    }
    }
    }
```

I know This means all the contents inside it will have namespace `A::B::C`, but does it also mean:

```
using namespace A
using namespace A::B
using namespace A::B::C
```

implicitly for the contents inside it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Because `obj` is not on the root (global) namespace if you write outside its namespace `Object` the identifier will be not found. So you have a few options:

- use fully qualified name:

  ```
  A::B::C::Object obj = ...
  ```
- use using declaration:

  ```
  using namespace A::B::C;
  Object obj = ...;
  ```
- use using declaration:

  ```
  using A::B::C::Object
  Object obj = ...
  ```
- use namespace alias:

  ```
  namespace X = A::B::C;
  X::Object obj = ...
  ```

And basically any combination of above e.g.:

```
namespace Y = A::B;
Y::C Object obj = ...

using namespace A::B;
C::Object obj = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Statements placed in the inner namespaces will be able to reference classes, typedefs, functions, etc from the outer namespaces without explicitly typing them.

```
namespace A {
    class AClass { };
    namespace B {
        class BClass {
            AClass a;   // Does not require A::AClass
        };
    }
}
```

In addition to `using namespace`, another way to shorten lengthy compounded namespaces in a .cpp file is to declare a new, shorter namespace:

```
// MyClass.h
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        class MyClass { 
        public:
            void f();               
        };
    }
}
```

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

namespace AB = ::A::B;

void AB::MyClass::f() {
    // impl...
}
```

(Note that the optional `::` at the start of `::A::B` explictly tells the compiler that `::A::B` is the full path, which is potentially useful if a header had an `SomeOtherSpace::A::B` namespace and carelessly wrote `using namespace SomeOtherSpace`.)

Comment: thanks Jack, what if `class AClass { };` is not defined in this file but another .cpp file under same namespace `A`, is it also true that I can still use `AClass a` and no need to write `A::AClass a`?

Comment: Yes; declaring `AClass` in namespace `A` in a .h file, defining `A::AClass` in a .cpp file, and `#including` the .h in a different .cpp file will allow you to use `AClass` in that .cpp file, either with `A::`, `using namespace A`, or by writing the code within a new `namespace A { ... }` block.